# Link cells from different sheets if the cells next to it matches

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the next function.

If the first cell in A in worksheet1 is equal to the cell in A in worksheet2 (where the function is called), then the empty cell next to it in column B of worksheet2, changes to the data of the cell next to it in column B in worksheet1. If they are not equal, then try it for the next row in worksheet1 until it finds a match.

The sheets looks a bit like this:

Worksheet1

```
A       B    

1 11:10   a

2 11:11   b

3 11:12   c
```

Worksheet2

```
  A      B        

1 11:11  function

2 11:14  function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub match()
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim FRow1 As Long, FRow2 As Long, m as Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim str1A As String, str12A As String

Set w1 = Sheet1
Set w2 = Sheet2

m=w1.Rows.Count

Frow1 = w1.Range("A"& m).End(xlUp).Row
Frow2 = w2.Range("A"& m).End(xlUp).Row

For i=1 to FRow1
  str1A = Trim(w1.Range("A" & i).Text)
  str2A = Trim(w2.Range("A" & i).Text)

 if str1A = str2A then
     w2.Range("B" & i) =""
 Else: End if

Next i

End Sub
```